# Program Architecture: How to manage objects that are interdependent

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, programming-practices, object-oriented-design

Consider the following case, image I making a simple chat program; I want it to be extensible such that it would be fair easy to add add different scripting and user interfaces.

I want the core controller and model to be separate from the interface so I could something like the following, I am using python syntax for simplicities sake.

```
 class chat_controller:
     def send_message():
     def add_new_interface(iface)


class console_ui:
    def __init__(chat_interface): #new need access to the chat ctrl
    def receive_new_message(msg):

class python_scripting:
    def __init__(chat_interface): #new need access to the chat ctrl
    def receive_new_message(msg):


c=chat_controller(...)
c.add_new_interface(console_ui)
c.add_new_interface(python_scripting)
```

This works, UNTIL I also want to the python interface to be able to interact with the UI (say alter colours, whatever) or until I want to be able to execute script macros from the UI.

On idea I had would be to have something like this:

```
 class chat_controller:
     def send_message():
     #register new interface with name
     def add_new_interface(name, iface)
     def try_get_interface(name) #none or iface
```

but then I'll have to do some cast relying on the string value to be correct, which is kind of gross.

Another way, would be to make each of the sharing objects to have an 'add_new_inteface' functions, but now it just seems cumbersome.

Bare in mind, it maybe the case that the chat program could be run with out python scripting, or with a different script engine, or say a web or GUI rather than console, it's supposed to be generic.

Any input is greatly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should have as few interdependent objects as possible. In your case, as I understand, chat_controller is not actually an initiator of events. It is more like a central manager of the system.

I guess what you need to do is to declare CharController as a class, that have methods, registering (pushing) various events, happening in the system to it, and then use Observer pattern to let various classes to subscribe to it's events.

But I am sure you will eventually find out, that there are many event types and ChatController will be split into several class, each responsible for a particular system function to avoid complexity.

But it's difficult to give some good advice until we know more of the nature of the system. What is it like? What does it do?